# Error processing incoming SOAPMessage with XML data

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I'm developing a web service which takes as input parameter two string values. The first identifies the service to use to import the xml data, and the second is a string of XML data. Here is an example of SOAP request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.dataexchange.xxx.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:importDataExchange>
         <ServiceID>XmlImportServiceName</ServiceID>
         <ExchangeData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><srv:exchange xmlns:cnt="Container" xmlns:core="Core" xmlns:srv="Service" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="Service http://xxx/xxx.xsd"></srv:exchange></ExchangeData>
      </web:importDataExchange>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately, whenever I try to parse the SOAPMessage, I received the following error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,28]]
```

This is clearly because the JAX-WS I've implemented is trying to Unmarshall the contents of the `<ExchangeData>` element. Of course, this can all be fixed by wrapping the contents of the `<ExchangeData>` in a `<![CDATA[ ]]>` element, however, I have no control over how the data is sent to the server. Therefore, I need a way to intercept the SOAPMessage and extract the ExchangeData as a string without Unmarshalling it. Or, I need a way to have the web service treat the contents of the ExchangeData node as a string rather than another XML node in the SOAPMessage body/payload.

I have tried implementing a SOAPHandler and also a LogicalHandler, but in both instances whenever Message/Payload is fetched the web server attempts to unmarshall the SOAP message, which reproduces the same error again.

This is the ImportServiceEndpoint that I've developed so far.

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

@WebService(serviceName = "ImportServiceEndpoint", portName = "dataexchange")
// @HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")
public class ImportServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportServiceEndpoint.class);

    /**
     * The soap implementation of the data exchange service.
     * 
     * @param serviceID
     *          the id of the service
     * @param exchangeData
     *          the xml data for the request.
     * @return a response about the success/failure of the dataexchange.
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "importDataExchangeResponse")
    public String importDataExchange(@ModelAttribute("ServiceID") @WebParam(name = "ServiceID") final String serviceID,
            @ModelAttribute("ExchangeData") @WebParam(name = "ExchangeData") final String exchangeData) {
        LOGGER.debug("Recevied Soap request for service {} with xml data '{}'", serviceID, exchangeData);
        return "Message Received";
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any assistance. I'm getting quite frustrated as I've been working on this for a couple of days now with little to show for it.

Comment: Remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from your `<ExchangeData>` block. You can't have a XML declaration there.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to leave it there as I'm going to pass the XML data in the '<ExchangeData>` block to another service for unmarshalling. My question is how can I treat the contents of the '<ExchangeData>` block as a string rather than as more XML content.

Comment: You can't leave it there. It's invalid XML. You *can* exchange data as XML, but you can't have a XML declaration in the block.

Comment: Ok, lets approach this in a different way. If I were to pass the values as XML data, then how would I declare the `exchangeData` variable in my `importDataExchange()` method?

Comment: I've played around with it and I see that I can add my generated JAXB class as a parameter to the method which would allow me to parse the XML content directly. Rather than Unmarshalling it later by the import service. Hopefully this solves my problem. Thanks for pointing out that the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` can't be in the `<ExchangeData>` it led me to the correct solution.... I hope.

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that the xml file was started by a blank line and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` was not the beginning of the file.

Removed the blank line and the problem solved.